# Is there any difference between these two random walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm implementations in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, simulation, bayesian

I'm trying to implement a random walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in R. I have used the the self-defined functions `logit` and `invlogit` to apply and undo the [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function. I have also used the normal distribution to add random noise. Given these two facts, once you use the inverse transformation on the transformed parameter + random noise, the proposal distribution is no longer symmetric, which is why I then apply the corrective term `log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))` to the acceptance probability.

My problem is that there seems to be two ways to implement this algorithm in R. If both of these ways were equal, then, as I understand it, I should be getting equal values for both when calculating `acceptanceRate`. However, this is not the case, which leads me to believe that one implementation is flawed (has bugs) and the other doesn't.

However, two other possibilities are that (1) both ways are incorrect or (2) both ways are correct and I'm misunderstanding something. I'm new to R coding, and I still can't understand why these deviations exist in the value of `acceptanceRate` between the two implementations.

Note: my specific problem of interest is why I'm getting different value for `acceptanceRate` between the two implementations.

**Implementation 1**

```
log.posterior <- function(p) (12+p)*log(p) + (9-p)*log(1-p)

B <- 10000           ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals
for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point
  logit <- function(p) log(p/(1-p))
  invlogit <- function(lo) 1/(1 + exp(-lo))
  yt <- invlogit(rnorm(1, mean = logit(xt), sd = 0.45))      ## proposal
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate <- num.accept/B
```

See how implementation 1 uses `yt <- invlogit(rnorm(1, mean = logit(xt), sd = 0.45))`? Everything is accumulated and done together.

**Implementation 2**

```
log.posterior <- function(p) (12+p)*log(p) + (9-p)*log(1-p)

B <- 10000           ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals
for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point
  logit <- function(p) log(p/(1-p))
  xt <- logit(xt)
  yt <- xt + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 0.45)      ## proposal
  invlogit <- function(lo) 1/(1 + exp(-lo))
  xt <- invlogit(xt)
  yt <- invlogit(yt)
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate <- num.accept/B
```

Notice that implementation 2 breaks everything down into separate pieces are proceeds sequentially.

Comment: too broad..........

Comment: @MitchWheat But it's about a specific value? Did you read the entire thing?

Comment: This is off topic. Voted to close.

Comment: @SmallChess is this better suited towards stats.stackexchange? I thought, since it was a code-specific problem, it would be suitable for here?

Comment: @Suren Oh? It seemed to me like it was. I will take it elsewhere if people think that’s more suitable?

Comment: I take it back. Maybe it is the implementation.

Comment: @Suren Yes, I was quite sure it’s my inexperience with R and lack of familiarity with how it deals with variables and such that may be causing the problems.

Comment: In implementation 1, you seem to use the `invlogit` before you declare it.  These function doesn't seem to be declared inside the `for` loop anyway.

Comment: You might want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Suren Thanks. That was a transcription error on my part. Fixed now.

Comment: @kath Thanks. Will take a look.

Comment: @ThePointer Apologies for hijacking this post, but I noticed you took down your recent rstan question. We were exchanging comments earlier. If still an issue, please undelete, and I can post an answer to clarify.

Comment: @MauritsEvers That's fine. I think I managed to fix the issue, but I've encountered new issues. If you have any time, I would, of course, appreciate any assistance you could provide: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342470/modelling-parameter-r-max-limits-i-1-dots-10-p-i-min-limits-i

Comment: @ThePointer Can I suggest that you re-open the previous question. I'd like to show a few optimisations, that might also help with your CV question.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have undeleted it. Someone voted to close it, so I thought it best to delete it. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  any chance you could look at my similar quesiton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709258/random-walk-metropolis-hastings-implementation-in-r-using-log-scale)?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I had a look at your question. I haven't touched this subject since the time I posted this, so I don't remember anywhere near enough to help you. The best I could do is give your question an upvote. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: @ThePointer don't worry! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using random numbers, so to have reproducible results you need to use `set.seed` before running your algorithms.
I pulled out the definition of the function from the `for`-loop and used `set.seed`. I got the same results in both cases:

```
log.posterior <- function(p) (12+p)*log(p) + (9-p)*log(1-p)
logit <- function(p) log(p/(1-p))
invlogit <- function(lo) 1/(1 + exp(-lo))
```

### 1st implementation

```
set.seed(42)
B <- 10000  ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals
for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point
  yt <- invlogit(rnorm(1, mean = logit(xt), sd = 0.45))      ## proposal
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate1 <- num.accept/B

rm(B, chain, num.accept, i, lapt, xt, yt)
```

### 2nd implementation

```
set.seed(42)
B <- 10000           ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals

for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point
  xt <- logit(xt)
  yt <- xt + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 0.45)      ## proposal
  xt <- invlogit(xt)
  yt <- invlogit(yt)
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate2 <- num.accept/B

acceptanceRate1
# [1] 0.7029
acceptanceRate2
# [1] 0.7029
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I see what's going on now! Thank you for taking the time to review!

Comment: any chance you could look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709258/random-walk-metropolis-hastings-implementation-in-r-using-log-scale) ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, OP compared the two functions that depend on random number generators without setting the seed (`set.seed`).

I don't see what is wrong with it. For a small chain, I get the same outcome.

```
log.posterior <- function(p) (12+p)*log(p) + (9-p)*log(1-p)
invlogit <- function(lo) 1/(1 + exp(-lo))
logit <- function(p) log(p/(1-p))

set.seed(1)

B <- 100           ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals
for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point

  xt <- logit(xt)
  yt <- xt + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 0.45)      ## proposal

  xt <- invlogit(xt)
  yt <- invlogit(yt)
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate <- num.accept/B
```

> ```
> # acceptanceRate 
> # [1] 0.69
>
> # chain[30:40]  
> # [1] 0.7674114 0.6612332 0.5867199 0.5867199 0.5744098 0.6033942 0.5359917  [8] 0.5359917 0.5359917 0.6040635 0.6040635
> ```

```
log.posterior <- function(p) (12+p)*log(p) + (9-p)*log(1-p)
logit <- function(p) log(p/(1-p))
invlogit <- function(lo) 1/(1 + exp(-lo))

set.seed(1)
B <- 100           ## number of realisations we want to have
chain <- rep(0, B+1)  ## vector to hold realisations
chain[1] <- 0.5       ## initial value
num.accept <- 0       ## keep track on how often we accept proposals
for(i in 1:B){
  xt <- chain[i] ## current point

  yt <- invlogit(rnorm(1, mean = logit(xt), sd = 0.45))      ## proposal
  lapt <- log.posterior(yt) - log.posterior(xt) + log(yt*(1 - yt)) - log(xt*(1 - xt))   ## acceptance probability on the log scale)
  if( runif(1) <= exp(lapt) ){
    chain[i+1] <- yt    ## accept proposal if runif(1) is less or equal to the acceptance probility
    num.accept <- num.accept + 1 ## proposal was accepted
  }else
    chain[i+1] <- xt    ## reject proposal
}

acceptanceRate <- num.accept/B
```

> ```
> # acceptanceRate 
> # [1] 0.69
>
> # chain[30:40]  
> # [1] 0.7674114 0.6612332 0.5867199 0.5867199 0.5744098 0.6033942 0.5359917  [8] 0.5359917 0.5359917 0.6040635 0.6040635
> ```

Comment: Oh, wow. So you're getting the *exact* same values for both implementations!? And thanks for the review btw.

Comment: Yes, because @Suren uses `set.seed(1)` before both runs.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much both of you.

Comment: So, you don't know about setting the seed! :)

Comment: @Suren I am a noob. :(

Comment: could you please look at my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709258/random-walk-metropolis-hastings-implementation-in-r-using-log-scale)?