# Random Walk Metropolis Hastings implementation in R using log scale

Tags: r, machine-learning, sampling, mcmc, random-walk

## Context

I looked literally everywhere but I couldn't find a complete implementation of the Random Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm using the log scale. By log scale I mean that we are working with the logarithm of the target distribution (which would usually be a posterior). For simplicity here I have a minimal working example in `R` but I would be happy also with a `python` implementation.

## Problems

I do not understand the following things:

1. If I use the log scale, should I also use a log-proposal?
2. If I use the log scale, does it matter if the function that evaluates the log of my target distribution is just **proportional** to the log target?
3. How should I implement it?

## Minimal Working Example Context

Bayesian Logistic Regression (with `0-1` labels) **log-posterior** is given by

[image: logistic regression]

I want to sample from this posterior using Random-Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. According to posts such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137710/metropolis-hastings-using-log-of-the-density) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242135/decision-rule-for-random-walk-metropolis-on-log-scale) and [this blog post](https://umbertopicchini.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/tips-for-coding-a-metropolis-hastings-sampler/) **it is better to use the log posterior**.

## Minimal Working Example - Random-Walk Metropolis-Hastings function in R

```
library(MASS)
rwmh_log <- function(start, niter, logtarget){
    # Set current z to the initial point and calculate its log target to save computations
    z  <- start    # It's a column vector
    pz <- logtarget(start)
    # Generate matrix containing the samples. Initialize first sample with the starting value
    samples <- matrix(0, nrow=niter, ncol=nrow(start))
    # Generate uniform random numbers in advance, to save computation. Take logarithm?
    log_u <- log(runif(niter))
    # Proposal is a multivariate standard normal distribution. Generate samples and
    # later on use linearity property of Gaussian distribution
    normal_shift <- mvrnorm(n=niter, mu=c(0,0,0), Sigma=diag(nrow(start)))
    for (i in 2:niter){
        # Sample a candidate
        candidate <- z + normal_shift[i, ]
        # calculate log target of candidate and store it in case it gets accepted
        p_candidate <- logtarget(candidate)
        # use decision rule explained in blog posts
        if (log_u[i] <= pz - p_candidate){
            # Accept!
            z  <- candidate
            pz <- p_candidate
        }
        # Finally add the sample to our matrix of samples
        samples[i, ] <- z
    }
    return(samples)
}
```

## Logistic Regression Data Generation to run the minimal working example

```
set.seed(123)
# Number of observations, mean and variance-covariance matrix for class 0
n1 <- 100
m1 <- c(6, 6)
s1 <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 10), nrow=2, ncol=2)
# Number of observations, mean and variance-covariance matrix for class 1
n2 <- 100
m2 <- c(-1, 1)
s2 <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 10), nrow=2, ncol=2)
# Generate explanatory data by sampling bivariate normal distributions
class1 <- mvrnorm(n1, m1, s1)
class2 <- mvrnorm(n2, m2, s2)
# Generate class labels. First n1 are of class 0, last n2 are of class 1
y  <- c(rep(0, n1), rep(1, n2))
X  <- rbind(class1, class2)
```

## Plot of the generated data set (just for fun)

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(X, y)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=X1, y=X2, color=as_factor(y))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=20)) + 
    labs(color="Class", title="Linearly Separable Dataset")
```

[image: dataset]

## Logistic regression log posterior to run the minimal working example

```
# NOTICE THAT X NEEDS A COLUMN OF 1s FOR THE BIAS
X <- cbind(1, X)
log_posterior_unnormalized <- function(beta){
    log_prior      <- -0.5*sum(beta^2)
    log_likelihood <- -sum(log(1 + exp((1 - 2*y) * (X %*% beta))))
    return(log_prior + log_likelihood)
}
```

## Running the Minimal Working Example

```
start    <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=1) # 3 because of the bias
niter    <- 2000
samples  <- rwmh_log(start=start, niter=niter, logtarget=log_posterior_unnormalized)
```

## Results of the Minimal Working Example

It errors, saying

```
Error in if (log_u[i] <= pz - p_candidate) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

which basically means that both `pz` and `p_candidate` become `-Inf`. What is happening??

Running this algorithm on the command line we can see that it does something for the first `102` iterations and breaks at the `103`th. The samples generated up to that point are pasted below. You can see how they blow up.

```
> samples[1:102, ]
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
  [1,]  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
  [2,]  1.41003898  0.7678739 -1.1686514
  [3,]  1.41003898  0.7678739 -1.1686514
  [4,]  1.41003898  0.7678739 -1.1686514
  [5,]  1.12738511  1.3976872 -0.4979555
  [6,]  1.12738511  1.3976872 -0.4979555
  [7,]  1.12738511  1.3976872 -0.4979555
  [8,]  1.68208878  2.7622693  0.2584510
  [9,]  1.68208878  2.7622693  0.2584510
 [10,]  1.68208878  2.7622693  0.2584510
 [11,]  1.68208878  2.7622693  0.2584510
 [12,]  1.48830009  3.6458290  0.5262860
 [13,]  3.13261741  4.2619841  1.1795437
 [14,]  3.13261741  4.2619841  1.1795437
 [15,]  2.02763486  5.2880473  0.7658672
 [16,]  2.02763486  5.2880473  0.7658672
 [17,]  1.96977976  6.9251877  0.6729261
 [18,] -0.68979341  7.6298268  1.1032108
 [19,]  0.24805648  7.7550307  1.6386097
 [20,]  0.40805008  8.9963608  1.0833313
 [21,]  0.10764974  9.1156086  2.8628342
 [22,] -0.38268725 10.3344574  3.1492587
 [23,] -0.38268725 10.3344574  3.1492587
 [24,]  0.85171606 10.1059391  4.4215254
 [25,]  0.30011080 11.1485574  3.7030592
 [26,]  0.61490763 12.6665140  3.2527206
 [27,] -0.89593039 12.3662036  5.6501731
 [28,] -0.53032703 13.1415187  5.6613023
 [29,] -2.97562829 13.3948230  7.2948707
 [30,] -2.97562829 13.3948230  7.2948707
 [31,] -2.67296962 14.8767398  7.1043539
 [32,] -2.34678595 15.0634645  7.4827778
 [33,] -2.28767265 15.1808296  7.7828163
 [34,] -2.28767265 15.1808296  7.7828163
 [35,] -2.22941911 15.9571394  7.8020756
 [36,] -2.22941911 15.9571394  7.8020756
 [37,] -2.22941911 15.9571394  7.8020756
 [38,] -3.61326092 17.1933051  8.8868507
 [39,] -3.61326092 17.1933051  8.8868507
 [40,] -3.61326092 17.1933051  8.8868507
 [41,] -3.61326092 17.1933051  8.8868507
 [42,] -1.81956128 17.3817482  9.3416200
 [43,] -3.16750568 17.4750150 10.0015226
 [44,] -0.79642112 17.6399588  9.8016328
 [45,] -1.32371016 18.3821248  9.1565188
 [46,] -1.32371016 18.3821248  9.1565188
 [47,] -2.34696374 19.0425533  9.5953375
 [48,] -2.51424008 18.6796395 10.4786403
 [49,] -2.51424008 18.6796395 10.4786403
 [50,] -2.51424008 18.6796395 10.4786403
 [51,] -3.36106702 20.5262499 11.9090427
 [52,] -2.63987051 20.3130838 12.9556715
 [53,] -2.63987051 20.3130838 12.9556715
 [54,] -0.43401179 19.8467996 13.6708499
 [55,] -1.07079158 19.0419739 14.5880249
 [56,] -1.07079158 19.0419739 14.5880249
 [57,] -1.07079158 19.0419739 14.5880249
 [58,] -1.65936235 21.3411496 14.1030373
 [59,] -0.98841697 21.9482180 14.3336541
 [60,] -0.09823962 23.8173624 14.0384963
 [61,]  0.02893740 24.2862548 14.9104612
 [62,]  0.02893740 24.2862548 14.9104612
 [63,] -0.72302884 24.7495870 15.4289650
 [64,]  0.13822989 26.9019761 15.0382800
 [65,]  0.13822989 26.9019761 15.0382800
 [66,]  0.04357883 26.8745540 16.2482905
 [67,] -0.88960758 27.9014297 16.9891905
 [68,] -0.68093651 29.0824771 18.7134528
 [69,] -0.43058184 29.8667399 18.7786067
 [70,] -1.29463115 31.0491849 19.9036095
 [71,] -1.24440787 29.5035870 21.8790285
 [72,] -1.24440787 29.5035870 21.8790285
 [73,] -1.55557884 31.5517166 20.5560774
 [74,] -1.99585038 32.3840898 20.3167258
 [75,] -1.99585038 32.3840898 20.3167258
 [76,] -1.99585038 32.3840898 20.3167258
 [77,] -1.89981602 33.6591331 22.0290308
 [78,] -1.89981602 33.6591331 22.0290308
 [79,] -2.44680063 34.6652981 22.4020355
 [80,] -2.44680063 34.6652981 22.4020355
 [81,] -1.60876820 35.8310586 22.4224862
 [82,] -1.45422863 36.5512324 22.7365438
 [83,] -1.18233421 35.5138059 24.0647585
 [84,] -0.24570214 37.0486802 24.1860769
 [85,]  0.03168349 37.4168439 24.8989192
 [86,]  0.03168349 37.4168439 24.8989192
 [87,]  0.03168349 37.4168439 24.8989192
 [88,]  0.03168349 37.4168439 24.8989192
 [89,]  0.24215122 37.5586010 26.5258005
 [90,]  0.24215122 37.5586010 26.5258005
 [91,]  0.24215122 37.5586010 26.5258005
 [92,]  0.58862001 39.3607620 27.9298507
 [93,] -0.27926896 40.1595364 29.2239346
 [94,] -0.27926896 40.1595364 29.2239346
 [95,] -0.27926896 40.1595364 29.2239346
 [96,] -0.27926896 40.1595364 29.2239346
 [97,] -0.17760335 40.9974928 29.4057818
 [98,]  0.43759118 42.1254915 29.5706227
 [99,] -0.13618441 42.4222319 29.9347374
[100,]  0.93734292 42.7479366 30.4868951
[101,]  0.93734292 42.7479366 30.4868951
[102,]  0.93734292 42.7479366 30.4868951
```

Looking at the value of the `log_posterior_unnormalized` on such samples we can see that it does indeed blow up to infinity.

```
> apply(samples[1:107, ], 1, log_posterior_unnormalized)
  [1]   -138.6294   -310.8512   -310.8512   -310.8512   -814.2805   -814.2805   -814.2805  -2196.6386  -2196.6386
 [10]  -2196.6386  -2196.6386  -2969.5265  -3877.5393  -3877.5393  -4299.3816  -4299.3816  -5418.8160  -6098.4219
 [19]  -6520.9842  -7102.3063  -8222.7219  -9253.5215  -9253.5215  -9933.2233 -10196.3848 -11024.7336 -12248.1868
 [28] -12816.9682 -13964.8656 -13964.8656 -14897.0547 -15285.9802 -15566.7016 -15566.7016 -16129.8982 -16129.8982
 [37] -16129.8982 -17662.7135 -17662.7135 -17662.7135 -17662.7135 -18160.6234 -18610.1692 -18687.7953 -18765.9209
 [46] -18765.9209 -19482.5643 -19800.5161 -19800.5161 -19800.5161 -22021.5857 -22595.2153 -22595.2153 -22838.3542
 [55] -22862.6686 -22862.6686 -22862.6686 -24129.0525 -24740.6719 -25905.4325 -26827.0686 -26827.0686 -27470.8678
 [64] -28779.8978 -28779.8978 -29565.7594 -30755.0321 -32768.3554 -33383.2801 -34951.9200 -35192.1701 -35192.1701
 [73] -35742.4804 -36158.4290 -36158.4290 -36158.4290 -38238.1653 -38238.1653 -39191.6603 -39191.6603 -40079.6649
 [82] -40818.7965 -40987.1734 -42216.0336 -42980.1015 -42980.1015 -42980.1015 -42980.1015 -44203.8974 -44203.8974
 [91] -44203.8974 -46483.0324 -47911.4547 -47911.4547 -47911.4547 -47911.4547 -48647.6199 -49606.0710 -50046.5853
[100]        -Inf        -Inf        -Inf
```

This makes me think that maybe the decision rule is not working properly? Maybe it's accepting samples that it should not accept?

## Strange Result: Should I sample the NEGATIVE log posterior?

Somehow if I use the Random Walk Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to sample the **negative log posterior** I get somehow sensible results? How is that possible? Here is my code to see what's going on.

```
start    <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=1) # 3 because of the bias
niter    <- 100000
samples  <- rwmh_log(start=start, niter=niter, logtarget=log_posterior_unnormalized)
```

If then we use the following plotting code

```
samplesdf <- data.frame(samples) %>% mutate(rn=row_number())
trace1 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X1)) + geom_line()
trace2 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X2)) + geom_line()
trace3 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X3)) + geom_line()
grid.arrange(trace1, trace2, trace3, ncol=1)
```

we get

[image: traceplot]

and with the following plotting code we get the histograms for each parameter coordinate

```
hist1 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X1, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
hist2 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X2, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
hist3 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X3, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, hist3, ncol=1)
```

giving

[image: histograms]

These results can be made even better by starting at the map estimate and using the inverse of the approximate hessian matrix as the variance-covariance matrix for the normal proposal.

```
set.seed(123)
# Number of observations, mean and variance-covariance matrix for class 0
n1 <- 100
m1 <- c(6, 6)
s1 <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 10), nrow=2, ncol=2)
# Number of observations, mean and variance-covariance matrix for class 1
n2 <- 100
m2 <- c(-1, 1)
s2 <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 10), nrow=2, ncol=2)
# Generate explanatory data by sampling bivariate normal distributions
class1 <- mvrnorm(n1, m1, s1)
class2 <- mvrnorm(n2, m2, s2)
# Generate class labels. First n1 are of class 0, last n2 are of class 1
y  <- c(rep(0, n1), rep(1, n2))
X  <- rbind(class1, class2)
# Add colum of 1s for the bias
X <- cbind(1, X)
# log posterior
log_posterior_unnormalized <- function(beta){
  log_prior      <- -0.5*sum(beta^2)
  log_likelihood <- -sum(log(1 + exp((1 - 2*y) * (X %*% beta))))
  return(log_prior + log_likelihood)
}
# define negative log posterior to be minimized by optim function
logtarget <- function(x) -log_posterior_unnormalized(x)
# optimize it to find hessian and starting point
r <- optim(c(0,0,0), logtarget, method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE)
# Start at the MAP estimate
niter <- 100000
start <- r$par
z <- start
pz <- logtarget(z)
samples <- matrix(0, nrow=niter, ncol=3)
# Use the inverse of the approximate hessian matrix for our normal proposal
vcov <- solve(r$hessian) 
normal_shift <- mvrnorm(n=niter, mu=c(0,0,0), Sigma=vcov)
samples[1, ] <- start
log_u <- log(runif(niter))
for (i in 2:niter){
  # Sample a candidate
  candidate <- z + normal_shift[i, ]
  # calculate log target of candidate and store it in case it gets accepted
  p_candidate <- logtarget(candidate)
  # use decision rule explained in blog posts
  if (log_u[i] <= pz - p_candidate){
    # Accept!
    z  <- candidate
    pz <- p_candidate
  }
  # Finally add the sample to our matrix of samples
  samples[i, ] <- z
}


samplesdf <- data.frame(samples) %>% mutate(rn=row_number())
trace1 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X1)) + geom_line()
trace2 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X2)) + geom_line()
trace3 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=rn, y=X3)) + geom_line()
grid.arrange(trace1, trace2, trace3, ncol=1)

hist1 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X1, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
hist2 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X2, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
hist3 <- ggplot(data=samplesdf, aes(x=X3, stat(density))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.05, alpha=0.5, fill="turquoise1", color="turquoise4")
grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, hist3, ncol=1)
```

giving the following two plots

[image: traceplot2]

[image: histograms2]

Comment: Outside of the context of the logistic regression, that error does not mean `Inf` is involved, it typically means `NA` is involved.

Comment: @r2evans true. I tested the code above without putting it into a function, but just running the loop. It stops after some iterations and the reason is that `Inf - Inf` is `Na`, which then breaks the `If` statement

Comment: For me, `Inf-Inf` yields `NaN` not `NA`. With that, `if (NaN) 1` errs with *"argument is not interpretable as logical"*, so could it be something else going on?

Comment: @r2evans If you try running the code in the console, just running the loop you'll find that it performs `107` iterations. At `i=108` it breaks. At that iteration the candidate is
`
         [,1]
[1,] 35.39553
[2,] 35.05563
`
and the the current value is 
`
         [,1]
[1,] 35.02456
[2,] 35.70304
`
so that both `pz` and `p_candidate` are `-Inf` and `pz - p_candidate` gives `NaN`

Comment: Ok, I see ... `0 < NaN` yields `NA`, that's the part I missed, sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @r2evans no worries!

Comment: BTW: what are you using `tidyverse` for? I see `MASS` and `ggplot2`, but nothing else.

Comment: @r2evans sorry I copied the wrong line of code, will delete it.

Comment: Yup, just rushing through things ... deleted that comment ... fyi, `forcats::as_factor`?

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure if `as_factor` is from `forcats` but it doesn't matter. That's just a plot to visualize the data

Comment: BTW for a derivation of the formula for the log posterior you can look [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.com/post/bayesian-regularized-logistic-regression-with-laplace-approximation-in-r/)

Comment: I've also tried with different versions of the log posterior, such as this
`new_log_post <- function(beta){
  linear <- X %*% beta
  num <- sum(y * linear)
  den <- sum(log(1 + exp(linear)))
  return(num - den)
}`